# What's wrong with my python function?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to design a recursive function that accepts two arguments from a user and puts them into parameters x and y. The function should return the value of x times y. My code is failing to execute correctly because of how I am trying to pass the x and y variable in the return statement but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
def main():

    #get the user to input a two integers and defines them as x and y
    x = int(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))
    y = int(input("Please enter a second positive integer: "))

    #make sure the integer selection falls within the parameters
    if (y == 0):
        return 0
    return x+(x,y-1)

#call the main function
main()
```

My traceback says:

> return x+(x,y-1) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int'
>   and 'tuple'

Comment: What are you hoping to compute with `x + (x, y - 1)` ?

Comment: @donkopotamus I updated my question but the answer is, "The function should return the value of x times y."

Comment: Why not just return x*y ...?  As the error says, you can't add an integer, x, to a tuple, (x,y-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`You might try something along these lines:

```
def main():

    #get the user to input a two integers and defines them as x and y
    x = int(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))
    y = int(input("Please enter a second positive integer: "))

    print recursive_mult(x, y)

def recursive_mult(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return 0
    return x + recursive_mult(x, y - 1)
```

The error you're seeing is caused by trying to add an int value `x` to the tuple of `(x, y - 1)`, where instead you probably want to be making a recursive call to some function with these values and add the result to x.

Comment: Thanks caffreyd I had something almost identical to yours and @Yoav Glazner answer but I was getting an error due to how I had the print statement. I corrected your print statement with appropriate brackets and accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():

    #get the user to input a two integers and defines them as x and y
    x = int(input("Please enter a positive integer: "))
    y = int(input("Please enter a second positive integer: "))

    print( mul(x, y) )

def mul(x, y):
    if y==0: return 0
    return x + mul(x, y-1)
```